# Displayed label for repeat group

Tags: commcare

[image]

I'm trying to change the label displayed on commCare when I'm using a repeat group. I'm using the repeat group to save food items, but when I add a new food the label on commCare is set to Food(index of the list). Is it possible to change that label?

Please find enclosed a screenshot of the form. (I want to change the "Food(1)" Label)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the text of the repeat group "Food" by modifying the "Display Text" in the formbuilder on CommCareHQ. However, I do not think it's possible to remove the "(1)" that denotes the iteration that it's on.